# limit number of paralel queries per client to mongoDB sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb

I have clients to mongoDB cluster sending alot of queries to same data based on indexed fields

in the form:

```
 db.test.find({ "x.y":"some_often_found_value"}).sort({"x.date":-1})
```

I see some of this queries request more then 200k documents per query from database that has more then 200M documents.
Please, advice how can I limit number of queries per user or some how reduce number of paralel executed queries as what I see now is that my primary shard is hitting 100% cpu usage due to the hight amount of paralel sorts caused by this queries ?

Thanks